# How can I delete the contents of an App Service app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to delete the contents of an App Service app (not the App Service app resource itself!) - how can that be done? "undeployment" so to say or let's call it "reset".

Comment: How have you deployed the content? Linux or Windows? App or container?

Comment: yes, I deployed it. No container. Linux.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf - You mean contents of `Azure Linux App Service` ?

Comment: yes, correct :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the below steps to delete the contents of the `Azure Linux App Service` from `Azure Portal`.

Navigate to your `Azure Linux App Service` => Under `Development Tools` select `Advanced Tools` => `Go`

[image]

- Select `Bash` and navigate to `wwwroot` directory.

```cs
cd site/wwwroot
```

- Run `ls`, you can see the deployed files.

[image]

- Now Iam trying to delete a file from the deployed files.
- Use the below command to delete any file.

```cs
rm yourfilename
```

***Example***

```cs
rm appsettings.Development.json
```

- Now again try to check the files by using `ls`.You can see `appsettings.Development.json` is not available.

[image]

- If you want to delete all the contents of any folder, then run

```cs
rm -r *
```

[image]

- So, to delete any contents of the folder, navigate to the root folder which you want to delete the contents from and run `rm -r *`.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up directly using the SSH in the app service, then navigating to `cd /home/site/wwwroot` and deleting everything (in the end the same as you did), then restart the App (will then also show the default page again).

Comment: `will then also show the default page again`, If the deleted page is not related to the default page in any way, Then obvious it shows the default page.

Comment: I meant the default page from Azure, not the default page from an app :-)

Comment: Yes, the default page of `Azure App` will be available until we have our `App Service` in the `Azure portal`.